# Show the keypad in a storyboard and set constraints relative to it?

Tags: ios, storyboard

Is there a way of showing the keypad entry within a storyboard? I'd like to have it displayed so I can see in the storyboard what the whole view controller layout will look like when the keypad is displayed.
If it is possible, then is it possible to set a constraint relative to its top edge?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can’t do that, because the keypad (the virtual keyboard, I assume) is not within your view, your window, or even your app.

You can of course pin things to a view that shadows the frame of the keyboard when it appears. But that is not the best way to respond to the keyboard.